# What is the meaning of this php line of code? (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

So today i play with the http://bambooinvoice.org/ source code and i found this line:

```
$id = ($this->input->get_post('id')) ? (int) $this->input->get_post('id') : $this->uri->segment(3);
```

I already understand the basic syntax use in codeigniter but hope someone can tell me what is the use of this symbol (?) between the two syntax? If it some kind of technique, what is the name of the technique? What is he trying to achieve with this line of code?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ternary+operator+php

Comment: `Ternary` operator; same as `if(($this->input->get_post('id')) == true) { $id =(int) $this->input->get_post('id')} else {$id=$this->uri->segment(3);}`

Comment: thanks so i know now it is called ternary operator. been wondering for ages about this :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ternary` operator; same as

```
if(($this->input->get_post('id')) == true)
{ 
$id =(int) $this->input->get_post('id')
} 
else 
{
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind post Variable "id" to $id if, it is set. Otherwise use the value of the third url-segment.

Comment: to add to this, if id is a post variable it the statement tries to typecast that variable into an integer value, wonder why didnt the coder did the same with uri segment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shortcut of these:

```
if($this->input->get_post('id'))
   $id = $this->input->get_post('id');
else
   $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

It is a ternary operator:
Syntax:

```
$id = (condition) ? value_when_condition_is_true : value_when_condition_is_false;
```

Answer (score 0):

$id = ($this->input->get_post('id')) ? (int) $this->input->get_post('id') : $this->uri->segment(3);

this: z = ( x > y ? x : y );
is like:

```
if (x > y)
{
z = x;
}
else
{
z = y;
}
```

this: $this->input->get_post('id')

mean you are in an object (class), with an other class "input" and use the methods get_post().

this:  (int) x
cast x as int.

He choose how assign id, if get_post() is different than 0 or "" use the value of uri-segment(3)